# iOS8: Resizing (static) cells after click on a cell causes error

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm trying to make my app iOS8 ready but ran into a strange problem. My table uses static cells, however I adjust alot of stuff in code. One basic feature in this table is my datePickerCell. This works similar to the calendar app from Apple. When you click on a cell containing a date, a cell below gets resized to the height of the DatePicker and will be shown. After clicking the cell again it will be resized again and is hidden like that. However when I use this code, my app crashes with the error:

```
*** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _classicHeightForRowAtIndexPath:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3318/UITableView.m:10772

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if(indexPath.section == 1 && indexPath.row == 2){
        if(self.datePickerEdit){
            return 164;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    } else if(indexPath.section == 1 && indexPath.row == 3){
        return 2 * self.tableView.rowHeight;
    } else {
        return self.tableView.rowHeight;
    }
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    BOOL changeOfPicker = NO;

    if(indexPath.section == 1 && indexPath.row == 1){
        self.datePickerEdit = !self.datePickerEdit;
        //This is only necessary since it has to be hidden during initial load
        if(self.expenditureDatePicker.hidden) self.expenditureDatePicker.hidden = NO;
        changeOfPicker = YES;
    }

    if(changeOfPicker){
        [UIView animateWithDuration:.4 animations:^{
            [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row+1 inSection:indexPath.section]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            [self.tableView reloadData];
        }];
    }
}
```

When I add a complete estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath method with the same code as above, it still crashes. If however I comment out the whole heightForRowAtIndexPath (and the estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath), my app works. However the cells won't be correctly resized and this is a no-go.

How can I solve this?!

Comment: Is putting table view reload code into an animation block a good idea at all? And those two lines together don't make much sense at all.

Comment: I have the similar problem. Any body has solution?

Comment: i too had the same problem. check the cell height is < 0.